# Getting no output while passing String parameters in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

In the given below these two queries the first query runs successfully and display the result but while running second query i am getting no output and no error.

So can any please explain why i am not getting output in second query.

```
String firstdate="2014-11-01";
String lastdate="2014-11-30";

//1 query       
getschedule=con.getreader_schedule("SELECT startTime,endtime,available,comments FROM   
reader_available_time WHERE startTime BETWEEN '2014-11-01' AND '2014-11-30' AND        
reader_id="+Integer.parseInt("136"));  

 //2 query
 getschedule=con.getreader_schedule("SELECT startTime,endtime,available,comments FROM
 reader_available_time WHERE startTime BETWEEN "+firstdate+" AND "+lastdate+" AND 
 reader_id="+Integer.parseInt("136"));
```

Comment: for string parameters you need to place in between single quote as done in query1 when passing static values. in query 2 pass as startTime BETWEEN '"+firstdate+"' AND '"+lastdate+"' ... and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Well when you doing second query and giving external parameters u need to do something like this.

```
getschedule=con.getreader_schedule("SELECT startTime,endtime,available,comments FROM
 reader_available_time WHERE startTime BETWEEN '"+firstdate+"' AND '"+lastdate+"' AND 
 reader_id="+Integer.parseInt("136"));
```

tihs is what i think its  should work.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should be using **prepared statements** in your queries, to avoid this kind of issues. For a tutorial on prepared statements(using java), check [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/preparestatement-object-example.htm)

---

To solve your existing query,

You are not getting output in the second query because, on substitution of the variables, your query would be:

```
WHERE STARTTIME BETWEEN 2014-11-01 AND 2014-11-30
```

which is wrong and bound to throw exceptions.
Correct query should be

```
WHERE STARTTIME BETWEEN '2014-11-01' AND '2014-11-30'
```

which implies, you should change your text to

```
 WHERE STARTTIME BETWEEN '"+firstdate+"' AND '"+lastdate+"'
```